# Hi I'm using flutter using the esc_pos_utils_plus library I want to print a picture on paper that shows me the count of this problem on the paper

Tags: flutter, dart

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFu1j.jpg)the problem is when I put the special code in the photo print There is no problem when I print texts

There are a lot of code I have tried and there are no results to solve this problem Please answer me, I hope the code is correct
This code:

```
 final ByteData unit8List= await rootBundle.load("image/new.png");
    final Uint8List imgByte = unit8List.buffer.asUint8List();
    final a = decodeImage(imgByte);
    print("errr:$a");
    final  resized = copyResize(a!, width: 151, height: 83);
    bytes += gen.image(resized);

     printer.add(bytes);
```

Comment: Please add your code, and your research effort to solve the problem.

Comment: final ByteData unit8List= await rootBundle.load("image/new.png");
    final Uint8List imgByte = unit8List.buffer.asUint8List();
    final a = decodeImage(imgByte);
    print("errr:$a");
    final  resized = copyResize(a!, width: 151, height: 83);
    bytes += gen.image(resized);

     printer.add(bytes);

Comment: Edit your question to include your code, don't post in comments.

Comment: The code has been added

Answer (score 0):

This library was derived from [esc_pos_utils](https://pub.dev/packages/esc_pos_utils). The issue of printing images was there from this plugin as well as in the esc_pos_utils_plus library you are referring and does not seem resolved yet.

In the esc_pos_utils GitHub repository there is a [pull request](https://github.com/andrey-ushakov/esc_pos_utils/pull/105/commits/56dd7ed7b6eb017766b3c1ad9ee0c2fce266fc2a#diff-0860d596d92e56c82ca506939f68dd5fbfa70b27cb44f3bc3721a277cfa1e73b) fixing this bug. Unfortunately both esc_pos_utils and esc_pos_utils_plus have not implemented this fix yet. Here are 2 possible work arounds.

Option 1. Download the esc_pos_utils_plus library files from GitHub.

Next copy the code fixes in the pull request for fixing the image print bug.
Next put the fixed library code in the root of your project
Next Import the library in your pubspec.yml as a path variable as below

esc_pos_utils_plus:
path: ./esc_pos_utils_plus

Option 2. Write an email to the library maintainers to fix this bug

...
In case you choose option 1. This is the code from the pull request.
When modifying the library in esc_pos_utils_plus v2.0.3 lib>src>generator.dart use paste the following code

```
 /*
 * esc_pos_utils
 * Created by Andrey U.
 * 
 * Copyright (c) 2019-2020. All rights reserved.
 * See LICENSE for distribution and usage details.
 */

import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:typed_data' show Uint8List; 
import 'package:image/image.dart'; 
import 'package:esc_pos_utils_plus/esc_pos_utils_plus.dart';
import 'commands.dart';

class Generator {
  Generator(this._paperSize, this._profile, {this.spaceBetweenRows = 5});

  // Ticket config
  final PaperSize _paperSize;
  CapabilityProfile _profile;
  int? _maxCharsPerLine;
  // Global styles
  String? _codeTable;
  PosFontType? _font;
  // Current styles
  PosStyles _styles = PosStyles();
  int spaceBetweenRows;

  // ************************ Internal helpers ************************
  int _getMaxCharsPerLine(PosFontType? font) {
    if (_paperSize == PaperSize.mm58) {
      return (font == null || font == PosFontType.fontA) ? 32 : 42;
    } else {
      return (font == null || font == PosFontType.fontA) ? 48 : 64;
    }
  }

  // charWidth = default width * text size multiplier
  double _getCharWidth(PosStyles styles, {int? maxCharsPerLine}) {
    int charsPerLine = _getCharsPerLine(styles, maxCharsPerLine);
    double charWidth = (_paperSize.width / charsPerLine) * styles.width.value;
    return charWidth;
  }

  double _colIndToPosition(int colInd) {
    final int width = _paperSize.width;
    return colInd == 0 ? 0 : (width * colInd / 12 - 1);
  }

  int _getCharsPerLine(PosStyles styles, int? maxCharsPerLine) {
    int charsPerLine;
    if (maxCharsPerLine != null) {
      charsPerLine = maxCharsPerLine;
    } else {
      if (styles.fontType != null) {
        charsPerLine = _getMaxCharsPerLine(styles.fontType);
      } else {
        charsPerLine =
            _maxCharsPerLine ?? _getMaxCharsPerLine(_styles.fontType);
      }
    }
    return charsPerLine;
  }

  Uint8List _encode(String text, {bool isKanji = false}) {
    // replace some non-ascii characters
    text = text
        .replaceAll("’", "'")
        .replaceAll("´", "'")
        .replaceAll("»", '"')
        .replaceAll(" ", ' ')
        .replaceAll("•", '.');
    if (!isKanji) {
      return latin1.encode(text);
    } else {
      return Uint8List.fromList(gbk_bytes.encode(text));
    }
  }

  List _getLexemes(String text) {
    final List<String> lexemes = [];
    final List<bool> isLexemeChinese = [];
    int start = 0;
    int end = 0;
    bool curLexemeChinese = _isChinese(text[0]);
    for (var i = 1; i < text.length; ++i) {
      if (curLexemeChinese == _isChinese(text[i])) {
        end += 1;
      } else {
        lexemes.add(text.substring(start, end + 1));
        isLexemeChinese.add(curLexemeChinese);
        start = i;
        end = i;
        curLexemeChinese = !curLexemeChinese;
      }
    }
    lexemes.add(text.substring(start, end + 1));
    isLexemeChinese.add(curLexemeChinese);

    return <dynamic>[lexemes, isLexemeChinese];
  }

  /// Break text into chinese/non-chinese lexemes
  bool _isChinese(String ch) {
    return ch.codeUnitAt(0) > 255;
  }

  /// Generate multiple bytes for a number: In lower and higher parts, or more parts as needed.
  ///
  /// [value] Input number
  /// [bytesNb] The number of bytes to output (1 - 4)
  List<int> _intLowHigh(int value, int bytesNb) {
    final dynamic maxInput = 256 << (bytesNb * 8) - 1;

    if (bytesNb < 1 || bytesNb > 4) {
      throw Exception('Can only output 1-4 bytes');
    }
    if (value < 0 || value > maxInput) {
      throw Exception(
          'Number is too large. Can only output up to $maxInput in $bytesNb bytes');
    }

    final List<int> res = <int>[];
    int buf = value;
    for (int i = 0; i < bytesNb; ++i) {
      res.add(buf % 256);
      buf = buf ~/ 256;
    }
    return res;
  }

  /// Extract slices of an image as equal-sized blobs of column-format data.
  ///
  /// [image] Image to extract from
  /// [lineHeight] Printed line height in dots
  List<List<int>> _toColumnFormat(Image imgSrc, int lineHeight) {
    final Image image = Image.from(imgSrc); // make a copy

    // Determine new width: closest integer that is divisible by lineHeight
    final int widthPx = (image.width + lineHeight) - (image.width % lineHeight);
    final int heightPx = image.height;

    // Create a black bottom layer
    final biggerImage = copyResize(image, width: widthPx, height: heightPx);
    fill(biggerImage, color: ColorRgb8(0, 0, 0));
    // Insert source image into bigger one
    compositeImage(biggerImage, image, dstX: 0, dstY: 0);

    int left = 0;
    final List<List<int>> blobs = [];

    while (left < widthPx) {
      final Image slice = copyCrop(biggerImage,
          x: left, y: 0, width: lineHeight, height: heightPx);
      grayscale(slice);
      final imgBinary = slice.convert(numChannels: 1);
      final Uint8List bytes = imgBinary.getBytes();
      blobs.add(bytes);
      left += lineHeight;
    }

    return blobs;
  }

  /// Image rasterization
  List<int> _toRasterFormat(Image imgSrc) {
    final Image image = Image.from(imgSrc); // make a copy
    final int widthPx = image.width;
    final int heightPx = image.height;

    grayscale(image);
    invert(image);

    // R/G/B channels are same -> keep only one channel
    final List<int> oneChannelBytes = [];
    final List<int> buffer = image.getBytes(order: ChannelOrder.rgba);
    for (int i = 0; i < buffer.length; i += 4) {
      oneChannelBytes.add(buffer[i]);
    }

    // Add some empty pixels at the end of each line (to make the width divisible by 8)
    if (widthPx % 8 != 0) {
      final targetWidth = (widthPx + 8) - (widthPx % 8);
      final missingPx = targetWidth - widthPx;
      final extra = Uint8List(missingPx);
      for (int i = 0; i < heightPx; i++) {
        final pos = (i * widthPx + widthPx) + i * missingPx;
        oneChannelBytes.insertAll(pos, extra);
      }
    }

    // Pack bits into bytes
    return _packBitsIntoBytes(oneChannelBytes);
  }

  /// Merges each 8 values (bits) into one byte
  List<int> _packBitsIntoBytes(List<int> bytes) {
    const pxPerLine = 8;
    final List<int> res = <int>[];
    const threshold = 127; // set the greyscale -> b/w threshold here
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i += pxPerLine) {
      int newVal = 0;
      for (int j = 0; j < pxPerLine; j++) {
        newVal = _transformUint32Bool(
          newVal,
          pxPerLine - j,
          bytes[i + j] > threshold,
        );
      }
      res.add(newVal ~/ 2);
    }
    return res;
  }

  /// Replaces a single bit in a 32-bit unsigned integer.
  int _transformUint32Bool(int uint32, int shift, bool newValue) {
    return ((0xFFFFFFFF ^ (0x1 << shift)) & uint32) |
    ((newValue ? 1 : 0) << shift);
  }
  // ************************ (end) Internal helpers  ************************

  //**************************** Public command generators ************************
  /// Clear the buffer and reset text styles
  List<int> reset() {
    List<int> bytes = [];
    bytes += cInit.codeUnits;
    _styles = PosStyles();
    bytes += setGlobalCodeTable(_codeTable);
    bytes += setGlobalFont(_font);
    return bytes;
  }

  /// Set global code table which will be used instead of the default printer's code table
  /// (even after resetting)
  List<int> setGlobalCodeTable(String? codeTable) {
    List<int> bytes = [];
    _codeTable = codeTable;
    if (codeTable != null) {
      bytes += Uint8List.fromList(
        List.from(cCodeTable.codeUnits)..add(_profile.getCodePageId(codeTable)),
      );
      _styles = _styles.copyWith(codeTable: codeTable);
    }
    return bytes;
  }

  /// Set global font which will be used instead of the default printer's font
  /// (even after resetting)
  List<int> setGlobalFont(PosFontType? font, {int? maxCharsPerLine}) {
    List<int> bytes = [];
    _font = font;
    if (font != null) {
      _maxCharsPerLine = maxCharsPerLine ?? _getMaxCharsPerLine(font);
      bytes += font == PosFontType.fontB ? cFontB.codeUnits : cFontA.codeUnits;
      _styles = _styles.copyWith(fontType: font);
    }
    return bytes;
  }

  List<int> setStyles(PosStyles styles, {bool isKanji = false}) {
    List<int> bytes = [];
    if (styles.align != _styles.align) {
      bytes += latin1.encode(styles.align == PosAlign.left
          ? cAlignLeft
          : (styles.align == PosAlign.center ? cAlignCenter : cAlignRight));
      _styles = _styles.copyWith(align: styles.align);
    }

    if (styles.bold != _styles.bold) {
      bytes += styles.bold ? cBoldOn.codeUnits : cBoldOff.codeUnits;
      _styles = _styles.copyWith(bold: styles.bold);
    }
    if (styles.turn90 != _styles.turn90) {
      bytes += styles.turn90 ? cTurn90On.codeUnits : cTurn90Off.codeUnits;
      _styles = _styles.copyWith(turn90: styles.turn90);
    }
    if (styles.reverse != _styles.reverse) {
      bytes += styles.reverse ? cReverseOn.codeUnits : cReverseOff.codeUnits;
      _styles = _styles.copyWith(reverse: styles.reverse);
    }
    if (styles.underline != _styles.underline) {
      bytes +=
      styles.underline ? cUnderline1dot.codeUnits : cUnderlineOff.codeUnits;
      _styles = _styles.copyWith(underline: styles.underline);
    }

    // Set font
    if (styles.fontType != null && styles.fontType != _styles.fontType) {
      bytes += styles.fontType == PosFontType.fontB
          ? cFontB.codeUnits
          : cFontA.codeUnits;
      _styles = _styles.copyWith(fontType: styles.fontType);
    } else if (_font != null && _font != _styles.fontType) {
      bytes += _font == PosFontType.fontB ? cFontB.codeUnits : cFontA.codeUnits;
      _styles = _styles.copyWith(fontType: _font);
    }

    // Characters size
    if (styles.height.value != _styles.height.value ||
        styles.width.value != _styles.width.value) {
      bytes += Uint8List.fromList(
        List.from(cSizeGSn.codeUnits)
          ..add(PosTextSize.decSize(styles.height, styles.width)),
      );
      _styles = _styles.copyWith(height: styles.height, width: styles.width);
    }

    // Set Kanji mode
    if (isKanji) {
      bytes += cKanjiOn.codeUnits;
    } else {
      bytes += cKanjiOff.codeUnits;
    }

    // Set local code table
    if (styles.codeTable != null) {
      bytes += Uint8List.fromList(
        List.from(cCodeTable.codeUnits)
          ..add(_profile.getCodePageId(styles.codeTable)),
      );
      _styles =
          _styles.copyWith(align: styles.align, codeTable: styles.codeTable);
    } else if (_codeTable != null) {
      bytes += Uint8List.fromList(
        List.from(cCodeTable.codeUnits)
          ..add(_profile.getCodePageId(_codeTable)),
      );
      _styles = _styles.copyWith(align: styles.align, codeTable: _codeTable);
    }

    return bytes;
  }

  /// Sens raw command(s)
  List<int> rawBytes(List<int> cmd, {bool isKanji = false}) {
    List<int> bytes = [];
    if (!isKanji) {
      bytes += cKanjiOff.codeUnits;
    }
    bytes += Uint8List.fromList(cmd);
    return bytes;
  }

  List<int> text(
      String text, {
        PosStyles styles = const PosStyles(),
        int linesAfter = 0,
        bool containsChinese = false,
        int? maxCharsPerLine,
      }) {
    List<int> bytes = [];
    if (!containsChinese) {
      bytes += _text(
        _encode(text, isKanji: containsChinese),
        styles: styles,
        isKanji: containsChinese,
        maxCharsPerLine: maxCharsPerLine,
      );
      // Ensure at least one line break after the text
      bytes += emptyLines(linesAfter + 1);
    } else {
      bytes += _mixedKanji(text, styles: styles, linesAfter: linesAfter);
    }
    return bytes;
  }

  /// Skips [n] lines
  ///
  /// Similar to [feed] but uses an alternative command
  List<int> emptyLines(int n) {
    List<int> bytes = [];
    if (n > 0) {
      bytes += List.filled(n, '\n').join().codeUnits;
    }
    return bytes;
  }

  /// Skips [n] lines
  ///
  /// Similar to [emptyLines] but uses an alternative command
  List<int> feed(int n) {
    List<int> bytes = [];
    if (n >= 0 && n <= 255) {
      bytes += Uint8List.fromList(
        List.from(cFeedN.codeUnits)..add(n),
      );
    }
    return bytes;
  }

  /// Cut the paper
  ///
  /// [mode] is used to define the full or partial cut (if supported by the priner)
  List<int> cut({PosCutMode mode = PosCutMode.full}) {
    List<int> bytes = [];
    bytes += emptyLines(5);
    if (mode == PosCutMode.partial) {
      bytes += cCutPart.codeUnits;
    } else {
      bytes += cCutFull.codeUnits;
    }
    return bytes;
  }

  /// Print selected code table.
  ///
  /// If [codeTable] is null, global code table is used.
  /// If global code table is null, default printer code table is used.
  List<int> printCodeTable({String? codeTable}) {
    List<int> bytes = [];
    bytes += cKanjiOff.codeUnits;

    if (codeTable != null) {
      bytes += Uint8List.fromList(
        List.from(cCodeTable.codeUnits)..add(_profile.getCodePageId(codeTable)),
      );
    }

    bytes += Uint8List.fromList(List<int>.generate(256, (i) => i));

    // Back to initial code table
    setGlobalCodeTable(_codeTable);
    return bytes;
  }

  /// Beeps [n] times
  ///
  /// Beep [duration] could be between 50 and 450 ms.
  List<int> beep(
      {int n = 3, PosBeepDuration duration = PosBeepDuration.beep450ms}) {
    List<int> bytes = [];
    if (n <= 0) {
      return [];
    }

    int beepCount = n;
    if (beepCount > 9) {
      beepCount = 9;
    }

    bytes += Uint8List.fromList(
      List.from(cBeep.codeUnits)..addAll([beepCount, duration.value]),
    );

    beep(n: n - 9, duration: duration);
    return bytes;
  }

  /// Reverse feed for [n] lines (if supported by the priner)
  List<int> reverseFeed(int n) {
    List<int> bytes = [];
    bytes += Uint8List.fromList(
      List.from(cReverseFeedN.codeUnits)..add(n),
    );
    return bytes;
  }

  /// Print a row.
  ///
  /// A row contains up to 12 columns. A column has a width between 1 and 12.
  /// Total width of columns in one row must be equal 12.
  List<int> row(List<PosColumn> cols) {
    List<int> bytes = [];
    final isSumValid = cols.fold(0, (int sum, col) => sum + col.width) == 12;
    if (!isSumValid) {
      throw Exception('Total columns width must be equal to 12');
    }
    bool isNextRow = false;
    List<PosColumn> nextRow = <PosColumn>[];

    for (int i = 0; i < cols.length; ++i) {
      int colInd =
      cols.sublist(0, i).fold(0, (int sum, col) => sum + col.width);
      double charWidth = _getCharWidth(cols[i].styles);
      double fromPos = _colIndToPosition(colInd);
      final double toPos =
          _colIndToPosition(colInd + cols[i].width) - spaceBetweenRows;
      int maxCharactersNb = ((toPos - fromPos) / charWidth).floor();

      if (!cols[i].containsChinese) {
        // CASE 1: containsChinese = false
        Uint8List encodedToPrint = cols[i].textEncoded != null
            ? cols[i].textEncoded!
            : _encode(cols[i].text);

        // If the col's content is too long, split it to the next row
        int realCharactersNb = encodedToPrint.length;
        if (realCharactersNb > maxCharactersNb) {
          // Print max possible and split to the next row
          Uint8List encodedToPrintNextRow =
          encodedToPrint.sublist(maxCharactersNb);
          encodedToPrint = encodedToPrint.sublist(0, maxCharactersNb);
          isNextRow = true;
          nextRow.add(PosColumn(
              textEncoded: encodedToPrintNextRow,
              width: cols[i].width,
              styles: cols[i].styles));
        } else {
          // Insert an empty col
          nextRow.add(PosColumn(
              text: '', width: cols[i].width, styles: cols[i].styles));
        }
        // end rows splitting
        bytes += _text(
          encodedToPrint,
          styles: cols[i].styles,
          colInd: colInd,
          colWidth: cols[i].width,
        );
      } else {
        // CASE 1: containsChinese = true
        // Split text into multiple lines if it too long
        int counter = 0;
        int splitPos = 0;
        for (int p = 0; p < cols[i].text.length; ++p) {
          final int w = _isChinese(cols[i].text[p]) ? 2 : 1;
          if (counter + w >= maxCharactersNb) {
            break;
          }
          counter += w;
          splitPos += 1;
        }
        String toPrintNextRow = cols[i].text.substring(splitPos);
        String toPrint = cols[i].text.substring(0, splitPos);

        if (toPrintNextRow.isNotEmpty) {
          isNextRow = true;
          nextRow.add(PosColumn(
              text: toPrintNextRow,
              containsChinese: true,
              width: cols[i].width,
              styles: cols[i].styles));
        } else {
          // Insert an empty col
          nextRow.add(PosColumn(
              text: '', width: cols[i].width, styles: cols[i].styles));
        }

        // Print current row
        final list = _getLexemes(toPrint);
        final List<String> lexemes = list[0];
        final List<bool> isLexemeChinese = list[1];

        // Print each lexeme using codetable OR kanji
        for (var j = 0; j < lexemes.length; ++j) {
          bytes += _text(
            _encode(lexemes[j], isKanji: isLexemeChinese[j]),
            styles: cols[i].styles,
            colInd: colInd,
            colWidth: cols[i].width,
            isKanji: isLexemeChinese[j],
          );
          // Define the absolute position only once (we print one line only)
          // colInd = null;
        }
      }
    }

    bytes += emptyLines(1);

    if (isNextRow) {
      row(nextRow);
    }
    return bytes;
  }

  /// Print an image using (ESC *) command
  ///
  /// [image] is an instanse of class from [Image library](https://pub.dev/packages/image)
  List<int> image(Image imgSrc, {PosAlign align = PosAlign.center}) {
    List<int> bytes = [];
    // Image alignment
    bytes += setStyles(PosStyles().copyWith(align: align));

    final Image image = Image.from(imgSrc); // make a copy
    const bool highDensityHorizontal = true;
    const bool highDensityVertical = true;

    invert(image);
    flip(image, direction: FlipDirection.horizontal);
    final Image imageRotated = copyRotate(image, angle: 270);

    const int lineHeight = highDensityVertical ? 3 : 1;
    final List<List<int>> blobs = _toColumnFormat(imageRotated, lineHeight * 8);

    // Compress according to line density
    // Line height contains 8 or 24 pixels of src image
    // Each blobs[i] contains greyscale bytes [0-255]
    // const int pxPerLine = 24 ~/ lineHeight;
    for (int blobInd = 0; blobInd < blobs.length; blobInd++) {
      blobs[blobInd] = _packBitsIntoBytes(blobs[blobInd]);
    }

    final int heightPx = imageRotated.height;
    const int densityByte =
        (highDensityHorizontal ? 1 : 0) + (highDensityVertical ? 32 : 0);

    final List<int> header = List.from(cBitImg.codeUnits);
    header.add(densityByte);
    header.addAll(_intLowHigh(heightPx, 2));

    // Adjust line spacing (for 16-unit line feeds): ESC 3 0x10 (HEX: 0x1b 0x33 0x10)
    bytes += [27, 51, 16];
    for (int i = 0; i < blobs.length; ++i) {
      bytes += List.from(header)
        ..addAll(blobs[i])
        ..addAll('\n'.codeUnits);
    }
    // Reset line spacing: ESC 2 (HEX: 0x1b 0x32)
    bytes += [27, 50];
    return bytes;
  }

  /// Print an image using (GS v 0) obsolete command
  ///
  /// [image] is an instanse of class from [Image library](https://pub.dev/packages/image)
  List<int> imageRaster(
      Image image, {
        PosAlign align = PosAlign.center,
        bool highDensityHorizontal = true,
        bool highDensityVertical = true,
        PosImageFn imageFn = PosImageFn.bitImageRaster,
      }) {
    List<int> bytes = [];
    // Image alignment
    bytes += setStyles(PosStyles().copyWith(align: align));

    final int widthPx = image.width;
    final int heightPx = image.height;
    final int widthBytes = (widthPx + 7) ~/ 8;
    final List<int> resterizedData = _toRasterFormat(image);

    if (imageFn == PosImageFn.bitImageRaster) {
      // GS v 0
      final int densityByte =
          (highDensityVertical ? 0 : 1) + (highDensityHorizontal ? 0 : 2);

      final List<int> header = List.from(cRasterImg2.codeUnits);
      header.add(densityByte); // m
      header.addAll(_intLowHigh(widthBytes, 2)); // xL xH
      header.addAll(_intLowHigh(heightPx, 2)); // yL yH
      bytes += List.from(header)..addAll(resterizedData);
    } else if (imageFn == PosImageFn.graphics) {
      // 'GS ( L' - FN_112 (Image data)
      final List<int> header1 = List.from(cRasterImg.codeUnits);
      header1.addAll(_intLowHigh(widthBytes * heightPx + 10, 2)); // pL pH
      header1.addAll([48, 112, 48]); // m=48, fn=112, a=48
      header1.addAll([1, 1]); // bx=1, by=1
      header1.addAll([49]); // c=49
      header1.addAll(_intLowHigh(widthBytes, 2)); // xL xH
      header1.addAll(_intLowHigh(heightPx, 2)); // yL yH
      bytes += List.from(header1)..addAll(resterizedData);

      // 'GS ( L' - FN_50 (Run print)
      final List<int> header2 = List.from(cRasterImg.codeUnits);
      header2.addAll([2, 0]); // pL pH
      header2.addAll([48, 50]); // m fn[2,50]
      bytes += List.from(header2);
    }
    return bytes;
  }

  /// Print a barcode
  ///
  /// [width] range and units are different depending on the printer model (some printers use 1..5).
  /// [height] range: 1 - 255. The units depend on the printer model.
  /// Width, height, font, text position settings are effective until performing of ESC @, reset or power-off.
  List<int> barcode(
      Barcode barcode, {
        int? width,
        int? height,
        BarcodeFont? font,
        BarcodeText textPos = BarcodeText.below,
        PosAlign align = PosAlign.center,
      }) {
    List<int> bytes = [];
    // Set alignment
    bytes += setStyles(PosStyles().copyWith(align: align));

    // Set text position
    bytes += cBarcodeSelectPos.codeUnits + [textPos.value];

    // Set font
    if (font != null) {
      bytes += cBarcodeSelectFont.codeUnits + [font.value];
    }

    // Set width
    if (width != null && width >= 0) {
      bytes += cBarcodeSetW.codeUnits + [width];
    }
    // Set height
    if (height != null && height >= 1 && height <= 255) {
      bytes += cBarcodeSetH.codeUnits + [height];
    }

    // Print barcode
    final header = cBarcodePrint.codeUnits + [barcode.type!.value];
    if (barcode.type!.value <= 6) {
      // Function A
      bytes += header + barcode.data! + [0];
    } else {
      // Function B
      bytes += header + [barcode.data!.length] + barcode.data!;
    }
    return bytes;
  }

  /// Print a QR Code
  List<int> qrcode(
      String text, {
        PosAlign align = PosAlign.center,
        QRSize size = QRSize.Size4,
        QRCorrection cor = QRCorrection.L,
      }) {
    List<int> bytes = [];
    // Set alignment
    bytes += setStyles(PosStyles().copyWith(align: align));
    QRCode qr = QRCode(text, size, cor);
    bytes += qr.bytes;
    return bytes;
  }

  /// Open cash drawer
  List<int> drawer({PosDrawer pin = PosDrawer.pin2}) {
    List<int> bytes = [];
    if (pin == PosDrawer.pin2) {
      bytes += cCashDrawerPin2.codeUnits;
    } else {
      bytes += cCashDrawerPin5.codeUnits;
    }
    return bytes;
  }

  /// Print horizontal full width separator
  /// If [len] is null, then it will be defined according to the paper width
  List<int> hr({String ch = '-', int? len, int linesAfter = 0}) {
    List<int> bytes = [];
    int n = len ?? _maxCharsPerLine ?? _getMaxCharsPerLine(_styles.fontType);
    String ch1 = ch.length == 1 ? ch : ch[0];
    bytes += text(List.filled(n, ch1).join(), linesAfter: linesAfter);
    return bytes;
  }

  List<int> textEncoded(
      Uint8List textBytes, {
        PosStyles styles = const PosStyles(),
        int linesAfter = 0,
        int? maxCharsPerLine,
      }) {
    List<int> bytes = [];
    bytes += _text(textBytes, styles: styles, maxCharsPerLine: maxCharsPerLine);
    // Ensure at least one line break after the text
    bytes += emptyLines(linesAfter + 1);
    return bytes;
  }
  // ************************ (end) Public command generators ************************

  // ************************ (end) Internal command generators ************************
  /// Generic print for internal use
  ///
  /// [colInd] range: 0..11. If null: do not define the position
  List<int> _text(
      Uint8List textBytes, {
        PosStyles styles = const PosStyles(),
        int? colInd = 0,
        bool isKanji = false,
        int colWidth = 12,
        int? maxCharsPerLine,
      }) {
    List<int> bytes = [];
    if (colInd != null) {
      double charWidth =
      _getCharWidth(styles, maxCharsPerLine: maxCharsPerLine);
      double fromPos = _colIndToPosition(colInd);

      // Align
      if (colWidth != 12) {
        // Update fromPos
        final double toPos =
            _colIndToPosition(colInd + colWidth) - spaceBetweenRows;
        final double textLen = textBytes.length * charWidth;

        if (styles.align == PosAlign.right) {
          fromPos = toPos - textLen;
        } else if (styles.align == PosAlign.center) {
          fromPos = fromPos + (toPos - fromPos) / 2 - textLen / 2;
        }
        if (fromPos < 0) {
          fromPos = 0;
        }
      }

      final hexStr = fromPos.round().toRadixString(16).padLeft(3, '0');
      final hexPair = HEX.decode(hexStr);

      // Position
      bytes += Uint8List.fromList(
        List.from(cPos.codeUnits)..addAll([hexPair[1], hexPair[0]]),
      );
    }

    bytes += setStyles(styles, isKanji: isKanji);

    bytes += textBytes;
    return bytes;
  }

  /// Prints one line of styled mixed (chinese and latin symbols) text
  List<int> _mixedKanji(
      String text, {
        PosStyles styles = const PosStyles(),
        int linesAfter = 0,
        int? maxCharsPerLine,
      }) {
    List<int> bytes = [];
    final list = _getLexemes(text);
    final List<String> lexemes = list[0];
    final List<bool> isLexemeChinese = list[1];

    // Print each lexeme using codetable OR kanji
    int? colInd = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < lexemes.length; ++i) {
      bytes += _text(
        _encode(lexemes[i], isKanji: isLexemeChinese[i]),
        styles: styles,
        colInd: colInd,
        isKanji: isLexemeChinese[i],
        maxCharsPerLine: maxCharsPerLine,
      );
      // Define the absolute position only once (we print one line only)
      colInd = null;
    }

    bytes += emptyLines(linesAfter + 1);
    return bytes;
  }
// ************************ (end) Internal command generators ************************
}
```

....

In library pubspec.yml

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter 
  image: ^4.0.15
  html: ^0.15.0
```